# How can I auto map with NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, automapper

I'm looking for software that can do the mapping for me in nhibernate.
I looked over for this but the only thing that I found was tools for fluent. I couldn't find anythings for clean nhibernate.

Is their such a tool?

Answer (score 1):

Nhiberante 3.2 has build in mapping by convention [ability](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2011/04/nhibernate-32-mapping-by-code_13.html).

Another way is to use [conform library](http://code.google.com/p/codeconform/).

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to take a look at the [NHibernate Mapping Generator](http://nmg.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the other answers, there are tools such as [Visual Nhibernate](http://www.slyce.com/VisualNHibernate/) that inspect your database and generate your mappings while providing hooks for you to customize the code generation process.